# Не работает regex в валидации формы html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

**Имеется форма в вэб-приложении:**

```html
<div class="col-12 mb-20">
   <label for="formLayoutUsername1">Имя</label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="formLayoutUsername1" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" required minlength="3" maxlength="10" required pattern="/[a-zа-я]/i">
</div>
```

В ней абсолютно отказываются работать паттерны с использование регекса, пишет просто "Введите данные в указанном формате". Но при этом `minlength="3" maxlength="10"` работают нормально. Проблема в регексе или express не поддерживает паттерны?

Приложение написано на node js с использованием express.

*Я хочу чтобы в форму можно было вводить только кириллицу и латиницу(заглавные и прописные буквы), но без спец. знаков.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="col-12 mb-20">
   <label for="formLayoutUsername1">Имя</label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="formLayoutUsername1" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]{3,10}">
</div>
```